# Populate array with file list in online directory

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, directory

Have to resort to your help once again!

I am trying to populate an array in html-javascript with file names in an online directory. Is this even possible?

Directory is http://timeactivitydiary.comyr.com/DATA/ so I would like a loop through the file names that returns

```
FilesArray[0] = "SampleDataset1";
FilesArray[1] = "SampleDataset2";
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Javascript is executed on the client machine, and so can't access your server's filesystem.

Comment: Where is the javascript executed?

Comment: it is executed within html

Answer (score 1):

How about jquery GET to grab HTML.

Then use jquery find to grab all link elements found in that HTML (as an unprotected directory in apache is a list with A-tags as directory files).

Lastly remove the first item as that is the Parent Directory link

```
$.get('http://timeactivitydiary.comyr.com/DATA/ ', function(data) {

    var $linkElements = $('a');
    var FilesArray = $(data).find($linkElements);
    FilesArray.shift(); 
});
```

I hope that helps.

You should beware of this though as it does leak security information to all users (i.e. this directory is unprotected) and if the right user finds this may lead them to asking more questions about the HOST server.

Be sure to take the time to ensure this server is properly secure. Apache give a brief document on best practices found here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html

Alternatively you could create a proxy script which the GET request calls and the proxy script could return the folders contents, moving it from a client-side to a server-side check. This way nobody will know where the files have come from or that this directory is unprotected. Something like:

```
   $.getJSON('/proxy-script.php', function(data) {
       //jquery code
   });
```

And proxy-script.php script:

```
<?php
   //call file contents 
   $json = json_encode($files_in_folder);

   echo $json;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I now understand why I couldn't find an easy answer on the web! May be a bit beyond me and beyond the scope of the project. Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this in pure JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://timeactivitydiary.comyr.com/DATA/", false);
xhr.send();
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
var lis = div.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")
var filenames = [];
for(var i = 0;i < lis.length;i++) {
    filenames.push(lis[i].innerText ? lis[i].innerText : lis[i].innerContet);
}
//here you should have a list of all file names
```

Basically, AJAX is used here. Please note that example is simplified a lot and is not cross-browser. Just search around the web how to do cross-browser ajax requests. Also, my code uses synchronous ajax request. Just for simplicity. Because of that your interface will freeze while request is executed.

Than I parse received html using created div (`xhr.responseText` contains HTML you see when open page in browser). Than I look for `ul` inside that div and `li`'s inside first found `ul`
Than just go through array of `LI`s and push file names into it.

You may use jQuery or similar library to do the same, but even if pure JS solution is more complicated,I think it is better to know how pure JS works before you switch to some libraries.

Or another option is to prepare that array on server with some server-side language like PHP. 
In that case you will be able to close directory listing and control what files should be shown to current user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I now understand why I couldn't find an easy answer on the web! May be a bit beyond me and beyond the scope of the project. Thanks anyway though